# mpl-token-metadata is breaks The React app

Tags: metaplex-js, react

When I added the following line to my project, I saw that it crashed and React.js did not build the page.

`import * as mpl from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";`

*Edit: I found some new information about my problem. if I import createMetadataAccountV3 it gives error. if I don't import createMetadataAccountV3 it doesn't give error. the problem is in this function. But i need this.*

and I get the following error in my console:
[image: error]

I think the problem is with the versions but I still can't solve it. I would be grateful if you could help me. Thanks. The package.json is like this:

`[
...
"@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^3.1.2",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi": "^0.9.0",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "^0.9.0",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters": "^0.9.0",
"@metaplex/js": "^4.12.0",
"@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.1.8",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.4",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.3",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.5",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-salmon": "^0.1.14",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.16.0"
...]`

`"devDependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
"@types/node": "^17.0.17",
"@types/react": "^17.0.40",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
"process": "^0.11.10",
"react-app-rewired": "^2.1.11",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"source-map-loader": "^3.0.1",
"typescript": "^4.5.5"
}`

Comment: I found some new information about my problem. if I import createMetadataAccountV3 it gives error. if I don't import createMetadataAccountV3 it doesn't give error. the problem is in this function. But i need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the application you are using.

I just [created a sample application](https://github.com/beeman/react-mpl-token-metadata-demo) that successfully imports `createMetadataAccountV3` from `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata`.

The app I created was built with the latest version of [create-solana-dapp](https://npm.im/create-solana-dapp) which is a great modern way to spin up new Solana projects.

On a side note, it's not recommended to import projects with the syntax below, as this breaks '[tree shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking)':

```
import * as mpl from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
```

Instead, try to import only the symbols you need, like so:

```
import { createMetadataAccountV3 } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
```

Another more complete app that uses the library above is this [Token Creator](https://github.com/jacobcreech/Token-Creator). Instead of creating a project from scratch, maybe that can help you get your project up and running quickly.